# Error:Could not load type 'test2' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field

Tags: c#

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  //[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

  public struct test
    {

         [FieldOffset(0)]
          public byte itemcode;
         [FieldOffset(1)]
         public byte method;/*1*/
         [FieldOffset(2)]
         public byte wavelen_1;/*1*/
         [FieldOffset(3)]
         public byte wavelen_2;/*1*/
         [FieldOffset(4)]
         public byte units;/*1*/
         [FieldOffset(5)]
         public byte temp;/*1*/
         [FieldOffset(6)]
         public byte slope_reaction;
         [FieldOffset(7)]
         public byte blank;
         [FieldOffset(8)]
         public byte slope_units;//mar 3
         [FieldOffset(9)]
         public byte num_stds;
         [FieldOffset(10)]
         public byte incub_time;
         [FieldOffset(11)]
         public byte num_read;
         [FieldOffset(12)]
         public byte decimals;
         [FieldOffset(13)]
         public byte std_repeat;
         [FieldOffset(14)]
         public byte sample_repeat;
         [FieldOffset(15)]
         public byte dmax;
         [FieldOffset(16)]
         public ushort regvol_1;
         [FieldOffset(18)]
         public ushort regvol_2;
         [FieldOffset(20)]
         public ushort samp_vol;
         [FieldOffset(22)]
         public ushort asp_vol;
         [FieldOffset(24)]
         public ushort linear_limit;
         [FieldOffset(26)]
         public ushort normal_low;
         [FieldOffset(28)]
         public ushort normal_high;
         [FieldOffset(30)]
         public ushort abs_limit;
         [FieldOffset(32)]
         public ushort delta;
         [FieldOffset(34)]
         public ushort delay;//100bytes
         [FieldOffset(36)]
         public float abs_high;
         [FieldOffset(40)]
         public float abs_low;
         [FieldOffset(44)]
         public float factor;//90 bytes


         [FieldOffset(48)]
         public float std_abs0;
         [FieldOffset(52)]
         public float std_abs1;
         [FieldOffset(56)]
         public float std_abs2;
         [FieldOffset(60)]
         public float std_abs3;
         [FieldOffset(64)]
         public float std_abs4;
         [FieldOffset(68)]
         public float std_abs5;
         [FieldOffset(72)]
         public float std_abs6;
         [FieldOffset(76)]
         public float std_abs7;
         [FieldOffset(80)]
         public float std_abs8;
         [FieldOffset(84)]
         public float std_conc0;
         [FieldOffset(88)]
         public float std_conc1;
         [FieldOffset(92)]
         public float std_conc2;
         [FieldOffset(96)]
         public float std_conc3;
         [FieldOffset(100)]
         public float std_conc4;
         [FieldOffset(104)]
         public float std_conc5;
         [FieldOffset(108)]
         public float std_conc6;
         [FieldOffset(112)]
         public float std_conc7;
         [FieldOffset(116)]
         public float std_conc8;
         [FieldOffset(120)]
         public float dmax_limit;
         [FieldOffset(124)]
         public float saved_reagentblank;
         [FieldOffset(128)]
         public float std_concentration;
         [FieldOffset(132)]
         public float intercept;
         [FieldOffset(136)]
         public float slope;
         [FieldOffset(140)]
         public float delta_limit;//161 bytes
         [FieldOffset(144)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
         public byte[] itemname;
         [FieldOffset(164)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
         public byte[] controlname4QC;
         [FieldOffset(184)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
         public byte[] reserved;

    }
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
      public struct test2
      {
         [FieldOffset(0)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 200)]
         public byte[] BARRAY;
         [FieldOffset(0)]
         public test P;



      }
     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        test P;
        test2 TT;
        TT.P.itemcode = 123;
        TT.P.method = 12;
        TT.BARRAY = new byte[200];
        //TT.BARRAY[1] = 12;
    }
```

when i write this code i got the error that Could not load type 'test2' from assembly 'structuretest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field. I want to set offset0 for both byte array in the test2 structure and object of the first structure.pls give me a solution..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `test2` does indeed contain incompatible fields at offset 0. `byte[] BARRAY` is a reference to an array; `test P` is a value-type. That cannot work. You could perhaps use a `fixed` buffer instead, but that is an advanced topic and probably isn't what you are trying to represent:

```
public fixed byte BARRAY[200];
```

In other news: mutable structs and public fields are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @user3952215 only if you want it to compile

Comment: Yes I want to compile it

Comment: @user3952215 then yes, you'll need to use `unsafe` to use a `fixed` buffer.